# How many solutions does $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod {365}$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How many solutions does $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod {365}$ have?

My thought:

$365 = 5 \times 73$ where $5$ and $73$ are prime numbers.

So we can obtain $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod 5$ and $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod {73}$.

For $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod 5$,

we checked $5 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, therefore it is solvable.

Using the Euler criterion, $(-1)^{\frac{5-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$.

Thus it has two solutions.

For $x^2 \equiv {-1} \pmod {73}$,

we checked $73 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, therefore it is solvable.

Using the Euler criterion, $(-1)^{\frac{73-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{73}$.

Thus it has two solutions.

So, there are four solutions in total.

Comment: That there are precisely $4$ solutions requires *proof*.

Comment: You can splice any solution mod $5$ with any solution mod $73$ using Chinese Remainder Theorem. To decide there are solutions modulo our two primes, it is enough to mention each is of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas may I have more hints on your approach or maybe an answer?

Comment: You have essentially given an answer, except that the solvability mod $5$ and $73$ could have been one line, and the CRT should have been mentioned for proof that each combination of solutions leads to a unique solution mod $365$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $5$ and $73$ are relatively prime, we have $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{5\cdot 73}$ if and only if $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ and $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{73}$.

Because $5$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$, the congruence $x^2\equiv -1 \pmod{5}$ has a solution, and hence two solutions. The same applies to $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{73}$.

Suppose that $(a,b)$ is an ordered  pair such that $a^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ and $b^2\equiv -1\pmod{73}$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, there is a unique $c$ (modulo $5\cdot 73$) such that $c\equiv a\pmod{5}$ and $c\equiv b\pmod{73}$.
Then $c^2\equiv -1\pmod{5\cdot 73}$, so $c$ is a solution of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{365}$.  Conversely, any solution $x$ of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{365}$ gives rise to such an ordered pair.

There are $4$ such ordered pairs, and hence $4$ solutions of the congruence modulo $365$.

**Remark:** The four solutions come in two $\pm$ pairs, so the task of **finding** them is only half as unpleasant as it looks. Actually, with the Chinese Remainder Theorem, once you have found $A$ and $B$ such that $73A\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$ and $5B\equiv 1\pmod{73}$, all four solutions can be written down mechanically. We do need to know that $\pm 2$ are the solutions of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{5}$ and $\pm 27$ are the solutions of $x^2\equiv -1\pmod{73}$.

The idea generalizes: there are $8$ solutions modulo $5^3\cdot 73\cdot 97^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Working modulo $\,73\,$ :

$$2^6=-9\implies 2^{12}=(-9)^2=8=2^3\implies 2^9=1$$

$$3^4=8=2^3\implies3^{12}=(2^3)^3=2^9=1$$

$$5^6=3\implies 5^{36}=3^6=8\cdot3^2=72=-1$$

Thus, we've found a primitive root modulo $\,73\,$ (namely $\,5\,$), and from here we get two solutions to $\,x^2=-1\pmod{73}\,$ : $\;\;5^{18}=(5^6)^3=3^3=27\;,\;-27=46\;$ , and the two solutions to $\,x^2=-1\pmod 5 \;$ are $\,\;2,3\;$

So we have the solutions modulo $\,365\,$ : $\;173\;,\;-173=192\;,\;338\ldots$ and I think that's all, folks: four different solutions: $\;27,\; 46,\; 173,\;  339\pmod{365}$

Comment: @RossMillikan , 27 is already there: my very first solution ($\,4-$th row from below). Thanks for the typo...and btw, I got **four** different solution and wrongly wrote three, so thanks once more. :)